# Compute exponential integral

Tags: complex-analysis

How to evaluate the integral of  $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\sin (e^{i \theta} )} d\theta$ ?

I try to use Taylor expansion but I'm stuck?

Comment: Looks a lot like $2\pi$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $$\int_0^{2\pi} e^{\sin(e^{i\theta})} d\theta = \oint_{S^1}\frac{e^{\sin(z)}dz}{iz}$$
which you can verify by substituting $z=e^{i\theta}$ in the right hand side.

Comment: @Math1 Do you know how to compute residues?

Comment: residue at 0...simple pole

Comment: I got it thanks.

Comment: @Math1 If you found this helpful, you can upvote and accept it.