Evaluate $\int_0^{2 \pi} e^{\sin(e^{i \theta})} \hspace{0.1cm} d \theta$
Evaluate $\int_0^{2 \pi} e^{\sin(e^{i \theta})}  \hspace{0.1cm} d \theta$

Here's what I have:
\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
        \int_0^{2 \pi} e^{\sin(e^{i \theta})} \hspace{0.1cm} d \theta &= \int_0^{2 \pi} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sin^n(e^{i \theta})}{n!}  \hspace{0.1cm} d \theta \\
        &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} \int_0^{2 \pi}  \sin^n(e^{i \theta})  \hspace{0.1cm} d \theta \\
    \end{split}
\end{align}
Substitute $\hspace{0.2cm} z = e^{i \theta} \implies dz = \frac{1}{z} d \theta$
\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
        &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} \int_1^1  \frac{\sin^n(z)}{z} \hspace{0.1cm} d \theta
    \end{split}
\end{align}
Isn't this just equal to zero? For two reasons:

By Cauchy-Goursat, the integral with bounds $1$ to $1$ can be interpreted as the contour $|z|=1$ (prior to the substitution) and since $\sin^n(z)$ is entire, we get a vanishing integral, hence a vanishing sum.

By Cauchy Integral Formula, the above integral (again with closed contour $|z|=1$ with $\sin^n(z)$ entire) equals $2 \pi i \cdot \sin^n(0) = 0$.


Heck, you may even be able to skip doing any work whatsoever because the initial integral $\int_0^{2 \pi} e^{\sin(e^{i \theta})}  \hspace{0.1cm} d \theta$ is a composition of entire functions and hence the contour integral over the curve $0$ to $2\pi$ immediately vanishes. But surely this cannot be? Otherwise, why would a problem like this be included in a text? I must be getting something wrong here.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3646968/42969 for a simple solution.

The correct substitution is:
$$ z= e^{i\theta }$$
$$ dz =e^{i\theta}id\theta = zi d\theta \implies d\theta = \frac{dz}{zi} $$
along with the contour $|z|=1$
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} \int_0^{2 \pi}  \sin^n(e^{i \theta})  \hspace{0.1cm} d \theta = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{\sin^n(z)}{zi}dz = \left(\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{zi}dz+ \underbrace{\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{\sin z}{zi}dz+\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{\sin^2 z}{zi}dz+...}_{=0}\right)  $$
It is easy to show the Cauchy integral formula is zero when $n\geq 1$ but not for $n=0$.
So
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{\sin^n(z)}{zi}dz = 2\pi $$

Let $z=e^{i\theta}$,then $d\theta = \frac{dz}{iz}$, hence the integral is just $$\frac{1}{i}\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{e^{\sin(z)}}{z}dz=(2\pi)\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{e^{\sin(z)}}{z}dz=(2\pi)(e^{\sin(0)})=2\pi$$
Due to the Cauchy integral formula $\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{z-a}dz=f(a)$. There is no need to expand $e^{\sin(z)}$.

Wow, that was slick!

There is a symmetry around $\theta=\pi$. The real part is even and the imaginary part is odd. So, just remain the integration of the real part tp get $2\pi$ as @Bertrand87 showed in his good answer.
